# where is a good place to seed my test data?

Tags: rspec, sinatra

I have tests that rely on db data.  I've been using factories to create the data on the fly with before statements in rspec describe blocks.

I'd like to move them to the start of the run.  Is there a good way to do this while continuing to use factories?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few ways to approach this. By default, the RSpec syntax

```
before do
end
```

is the same as

```
before :each do
end
```

This means that the code within the before block is called before EACH spec.

However, you can also use:

```
before :all do
  #...
end
```

which runs the enclosing code ONCE for the describe (or its alias context) block in which it is defined. However, you should be careful using `before :all` because it means that your tests will no longer run in isolation depending on what you define in the `before :all` block.

If you want to write code that runs once before your entire suite, there's also the option before(:suite) and after(:suite) that you can define within the RSpec configurations within your spec_helper file.

A more common approach is to use an RSpec method called 'let' that accepts one argument and one block. It looks something like this:

let(:foo) { FactoryGirl.create :user }

In a nutshell, the `let` method creates a method alias `foo` that returns the value of the returning block (`FactoryGirl.create :user` in the above example). The benefit is (1) it caches this variable so the block only gets once and (2) it is lazily evaluated so it only runs and caches the value in the block once foo is called within your tests. It's important to remember that sometimes this lazy evaluation can cause unexpected behavior in some cases. You can use `let!` instead to prevent lazy loading. The `let` method is run before any `before` statements, so you can use any method defined by `let` in your `before` block.

Finally, there's a project called FactoryGirl Seeds that allows you to define generators in your spec_helper that only run once. Haven't used it too much personally so I'm not sure how reliable it is but you can find more information here:

https://github.com/evrone/factory_girl-seeds